# How to print showing shared structure?

Tags: printing, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

As an example, the two expressions evaluated below have the same "printed" representation, namely `((A) (A))`, but they have very different *internal* structure. Here the structure is *shared*:

```
* (let ((item '(a))) (list item item))
((A) (A))
```

Here each `(a)` is a distinct entity:

```
* '((a) (a))
((A) (A))
```

Specifically, the value of the first expression is a two-element list were the two elements are *identical*; the value of the second expression is also a two-element list, but its two elements are *distinct* (i.e. *not* identical).

How can I represent these two values in a way that makes this difference in their internal structures more apparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`*print-circle*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_cir.htm):

```lisp
* (setq *print-circle* t)
T
* '((a) (a))
((A) (A))
* (let ((item '(a))) (list item item))
(#1=(A) #1#)
```

If you want "*[`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) -
[`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) consistency*", you should investigate
[`*print-readably*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_rda.htm) and
[`with-standard-io-syntax`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_std_.htm):

```lisp
(equal (read-from-string (with-standard-io-syntax (write-to-string x)))
       x)
```

should either return `T` or signal an error of type
[`print-not-readable`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/e_pr_not.htm).